# How to add attribute to S3 class with inheritance?

Tags: r, oop

I have a class constructor :

```
particle <- function(Charge=0, Spin=0, Energy=0, P=c(0,0,0), X=c(0,0,0), M=0){
    structure(list(), class='particle', charge=Charge, spin=Spin, energy=Energy,
              p=P, x=X, m=M)
}
```

I want to create a class that inherits the class variables of the particle class and adds an additional variable, `composite`.

```
fermion <- function(Spin=0.5){
    particle(Spin=0.5)
    composite = TRUE
}
```

If I use my classes now...

```
> f <- fermion(1.5)
> f
$composite
[1] TRUE
```

This is not what I want. Instead I want something like:

```
> f
list()
attr(,"class")
[1] "particle"
attr(,"charge")
[1] 0
attr(,"spin")
[1] 0.5
attr(,"energy")
[1] 0
attr(,"p")
[1] 0 0 0
attr(,"x")
[1] 0 0 0
attr(,"m")
[1] 0
attr(,"composite")
[1] TRUE
```

QUESTION : If I inherit the properties of a class from another class, how do I add a new attribute?  In Python it would be something like `self.composite=TRUE`.

Comment: I think S3 classes may not be for you - they are too simple. They really only handle function dispatch, attributes and other object properties are just taken on trust.

Comment: I agree. R works much better as a functional language rather than an object-oriented one. Often directly translating code from other languages line by line turns into an ugly mess.

Comment: That said, a function in R (in absence of a `return()`) call, returns the last line. The last line of your function is `composite = TRUE`, so it calls `particle`, does nothing with the result, and then returns `TRUE`. Instead `fermion()` should do something like `p = particle(Spin = 0.5); attr(p, "composite") = TRUE; return(p)`.

Comment: @MrFlick, fair point.  Given the option I'd prefer using C or Python, however I'm trying to understand a piece of R code given to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This creates an object of class `c("fermion", "particle")` with all of particle's attributes plus composite:

```
fermion <- function(Spin=0.5, ...){
    structure(particle(Spin=Spin, ...), class = c("fermion", "particle"), composite = TRUE)
}

# test
str(fermion())
```

giving:

```
 list()
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "fermion" "particle"
 - attr(*, "charge")= num 0
 - attr(*, "spin")= num 0.5
 - attr(*, "energy")= num 0
 - attr(*, "p")= num [1:3] 0 0 0
 - attr(*, "x")= num [1:3] 0 0 0
 - attr(*, "m")= num 0
 - attr(*, "composite")= logi TRUE
```

Note that if you just want to add composite = TRUE to a single `"particle"` object and change its Spin to 0.5 rather than create a whole new class then you can do this:

```
p <- particle()
p2 <- structure(p, Spin = 0.5, composite = TRUE)
```

Comment: Is it necessary to pass the ellipses as arguments?  It seems to work just as well without them.

Comment: If you want to be able to set the other arguments of `particle` then you do need that.  If it is sufficient to only set Spin and no other argument then it could be omitted.